# Visual Studio 2017/19 Docker Compose command does not launch containers

Tags: visual-studio, docker, docker-compose

I've got a .NET MVC solution with `docker-compose` project. When I run Docker Compose in Visual Studio I can see that at some point containers are launched and IP address appears in the logs:

```
1>docker-compose  -f "C:\Users\<user>\Source\docker\docker-compose.yml" -p dockercompose18429431017078490850 --no-ansi build
...
version: '2.4'
========== Debugging ==========
========== Debugging ==========
========== Debugging ==========
========== Closing Solution ==========
Shutting down running containers.
========== Debugging ==========
docker ps --filter "status=running" --filter "name=dockercompose18429431017078490850_ocm_" --format {{.ID}} -n 1
bc67076d592a
docker inspect --format="{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}} {{end}}" bc67076d592a
172.27.245.15
```

There is another solution which contains identical `docker-compose.yml` file and *.NET Core* library (unless I'm missing smth, that's the only noticable diff). When I run this solution, the containers are created but do not launched:

```
docker-compose  -f "C:\Users\<user>\Source\Demo1\docker\docker-compose.yml" -f "C:\Users\<user>\Source\Demo1\docker\obj\Docker\docker-compose.vs.release.g.yml" -p dockercompose14173384417294192453 --no-ansi config
...
version: '2.4'
========== Debugging ==========
```

The containers are OK. I can successfully run them from a command line.

I tried to run it in both VS 2019 and 2017, Debug and Release configurations. No luck. Any clue what may prevent the containers from starting within Visual Studio?

**Updated:** What I see in VS:
[image]

Comment: Which configuration are you running?

Comment: Debug, Release... tried both. Or what do you mean?

Comment: Did you select in drop-down that you should run containers?

Comment: Attached printscreen. It looks the same for cases when containers run and when they don't...